# What are the names of four Databases in SharePoint 2010 server that were replaced with single database in SharePoint Server 2013?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010, sql-server-2012, sharepoint-2013

I am exploring MS Project Server 2013. But I am kind of new to MS SharePoint 2013 Server.
I was going through the administration documentation for SharePoint 2013 Server. Somewhere there it is mentioned that in order to optimize for cloud architecture, MS optimized the four database from MS SharePoint Server 2010 to one single database in MS SharePoint 2013 server.

What are the names of these database in SharePoint 2010 Server ?
And what is the name of the new database (that replaced the 4 DB from previous version) in SharePoint 2013 ?

Comment: The four standard DB that I am aware of for SQL Server databases are master, Model, MSDB and tempDb. Not sure if Microsoft has merged all of them into one DB in MS SharePoint 2013 server.

Comment: I found the name of the four DB and one more: Draft, Published, Archive and SharePoint Content DB. So looks like there are 5 DB in MS SharePoint 2010 server. Here is the link to article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc973099(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Draft, Published, Archive and Reporting are Project Server databases not SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought that the SQL Server DB is shared and integrated with both Project Server and SharePoint Server 2013.